# Is there a key to suppress anchors in the VS Windows Forms designer?

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2008

I have anchors set for numerous control on a Windows form, and now I want to resize the form in the designer without anchors being applied. Is there a key to suppress anchors in the designer temporarily?

In the Visual DataFlex Studio, for example, we added the ability to hold down the Ctrl key while resizing in the designer for just this purpose.

Comment: Even changing the size in the Properties panel respects the anchors.

The only workaround I have found is to edit the size manually in InitializeComponent in the ClassName.Designer.cs file.

Comment: The workaround I come up with is moving all anchors from the «Formα.Designer.cs» into the Load hook of the form *(i.e. the one that's running on startup)*.

Answer (score 1):

I have searched high and low on Google and MSDN for you and have not found any valuable information. Or any relative info for that matter... So, I don't think it is possible. I've also tried experimenting with Visual Studio Express Edition myself, to see if it could be done but I couldn't get it to suppress the anchors.

I'm also interested in this, and if I find something, then I'll post it here for you.

P.S. What I have started doing is leaving the anchor properties until the very end. I know it's not much help, but it's the best that can be done until a better solution is found.

Comment: I'm interested in this, too, should you discover more.

Comment: I just came across this post again and thought I'd just let yah know that I haven't found anything yet - but am still looking.